# Python:Comparing the strings in two files and printing the match does not works properly

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to compare the strings of file "formatted_words.txt" with another customised file "dictionary.txt" and in the output I am trying to print those words from "formatted_words.txt"[formatted_words file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CcyxbY9vi849xvRcjb1VqeWwutSE7bt0) which are present in file "dictionary.txt"[dictionary file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I5_4iSATQZsBiazepkFOrcD2fm0EVU49).

```
from itertools import izip
with open("formatted_words.txt") as words_file:
    with open("dictionary.txt") as dict_file:
        all_strings = list(map(str.strip,dict_file))
        for word in words_file:
            for a_string in all_strings:
               if word in a_string:
                  print a_string
```

Nevertheless, in the output, all the words of the file "formatted_words.txt" are getting printed, though many words from this file are not in the "dictionary.txt".I cannot use any builtin python dictionary.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sets:

```
with open('formatted_words.txt') as words_file:
    with open('dictionary.txt') as dict_file:
         all_strings = set(map(str.strip, dict_file))
         words = set(map(str.strip, words_file))
         for word in all_strings.intersection(words):
             print(word)
```

Prints nothing because the intersection is empty